# Difference between 不得不， 不免 and 必然?

Tags: mandarin, usage, difference

All of these words mean must or inevitable, but is there a difference between them?

Comment: instead of the adjective "inevitable", to use a single translation for all 3, the adverb "inevitably" may be more appropriate, or as predicate "it is inevitable"

Comment: ＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂has ３ triples：必定／必然／一定，不得不／不能不／不会不，不得不／只得／只好。必定（副）／必然（副；形）／一定（副；形）［相同］都是副词，作状语，加强肯定的语气，强调＂肯定是这样＂。经常可以互换，稍有不同：＂必定、一定＂主要强调说话人根据情况对事物的判断，主观性强；＂必然＂主要是从客观规律、道理上判断，客观性强。＂必定、必然＂多用于书面语，＂一定＂口语和书面语都用。１坚持多听多说，听说能力必定会提高。（必然✓一定✓）２天天打太极拳必定对身体有好处。（必然✓一定✓）３只要你付出努力，必然有收获。（必定✓一定✓）４只要继续努力，你的理想必然会实现。（必定✓一定✓）５如果自己解决不了，她一定会来找你帮忙。（必定✓必然✓）６骄傲的人一定会犯错误。（必定✓必然✓）［不同］１。有判断词＂是＂的判断句中用＂必定、一定＂，不能用＂必然＂：１我看，他必定是在中山大学学习的外国留学生。（一定✓必然✗）２从饮食习惯来看，他必定是南方人。（一定✓必然✗）３听口音，他一定是北京人。（必定✓必然✗）４看样子，她一定是个演员。（必定✓必然✗）２。＂必定、一定＂还可以用在第一人称的句子中，表示说话人态度坚决，不过＂一定＂更常用，特别在口语中，很少使用＂必定＂；＂一定＂可以和＂要＂连用，可以用在祈使句中，＂必定＂不能：１你放心，东西我一定按时送到。（必定✓必然✗）

Comment: １他叫我去，我不得不去。（不能不✓不会不✗）２在飞机上，不得不关手机。（不能不✓不会不✗）３明天的会议很重要，你不能不参加。（不得不✓不会不✗）４他病得很厉害，不能不去医院看病。（不得不✓不会不✗）２。＂不能不，不会不＂有时可以互换，但意思也有一些不同：＂不会不＂是根据情理做出的估计，猜测；＂不能不＂强调主观上认为不这样不行，一定要这样：１你是他的哥哥，不能不帮他。（不会不✓不得不✗） ２他们是我的父母，我不能不管他们。（不会不✓不得不✗）３我请了他几次，他今天不会不来吧？ （不能不✓不得不✗）４我想，他结婚不会不通知我吧？（不能不✓不得不✗）［不同］１。＂不会不＂是根据情理做出的估计、猜测，表示情况应该是、很有可能是这样的；明显表示估计猜测时，用＂不会不＂：１您能来，他们不会不高兴。（不能不✗不得不✗）２这件事都登报了，你父母不会不知道。（不能不✗不得不✗）３他们曾经是邻居，见了面不会不认识。（不能不✗不得不✗）４我们考得那么好，老师不会不满意。（不能不✗不得不✗）２。＂不得不＂强调不愿意、无奈，句子明显有＂不愿意、无奈＂的意思时，用＂不得不＂：１陈明受伤严重，不得不放弃了比赛。（不会不✗不能不✗）２为了保住林勇的生命，医生不得不截掉了他的右腿。（不会不✗不能不✗）３为了给孩子治病，他不得不卖掉了房子。（不会不✗不能不✗）３。＂不能不＂后面可以带表示情感状态的动词，

Answer (score 2):

- 不得不: have to, there are factors/reasons that force someone to (do something)

  > 由于过热，我**不得不**关闭机器
  >   I **have to** turn off the machine due to overheating.
  >   I **have no choice but** to turn off the machine due to overheating.
- 不免/难免: would naturally; cannot help but.[1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E5%85%8D#Adverb) (It sounds more like reasonable than inevitable. See example below)

  > 工作量大，**不免**会有失误。
  >   It'd be **normal** to make mistakes due to the high workload.
  >   (The mistakes can be avoided if careful enough. But due to the workload it is very **reasonable** to make mistakes. You can use 必然 here)
- 必然: inevitable, certain. (At least the speaker believes so. There may be reasons, or there may be none)

  > 宇宙中必然有其他生命存在。
  >   There must be other forms of life in the universe.
  >   (The speaker believes so, but he doesn't necessarily prove it. There may be no reason given for the statement)